# Is negabinary representation unique?

Tags: binary

Is a negabinary representation of a number unique?

I'm wondering since negabinary has negative numbers, so some value can be counterparted. Is that representation unique?

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily shown to be unique. Representing an integer in negabinary works the same way as it does in any other base, negative or not: you divide by the base, record the positive remainder, and then repeat, concatenating all the remainders.

Since the remainder of a division is unique, it follows that the whole representation is unique.

Comment: But `0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1` and 
`0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1` are all representation of 3334. Right?

Comment: No, they are representations of 38608429_10 and -2285_10, respectively. 3334_10 is 1110100011010_-2.

Comment: Ah, I see, you wrote them backwards. In that case, the answer is also no: 1110100011010_-2 is 3334_10 and 1011111001000110101110100110_-2 is -157018526_10.